# camanjs crop, result render to <img> element instead of canvas

Tags: javascript, camanjs

I'm doing good with caman, I came across with cropping and wants to render the result to `<img>` directly, not to canvas

```
Caman("#xxx-img", function () {
    this.crop(100, 100,0,0);
    this.render(function());
});
```

is it possible to render to `<img>` directly? any ideas, help?

Answer (score 2):

[image]

You have to convert on base64 like this :

```js
document.getElementById("crop").addEventListener("click", function() {
  Caman("#xxx-img", function() {
    this.crop(500, 286, 0, 0);
    this.render(function() {
      var image = this.toBase64();
      document.body.innerHTML = '<img src="' + image + '" />';
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/camanjs/4.1.2/caman.full.js"></script>
<input id="crop" type="button" value="crop" />
<br>
<img id=xxx-img width="200px" src=" data:image/png;base64,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"
/>
```

Comment: @JuliverGalleto You can remove it